How to navigate to a route with query parameters before creating a component instance in Angular integration tests?
I have a component with the following route configuration:
    {
        path: "offers",
        loadComponent: () => import('./offer-details/containers/offer-details/offer-details.component').then((m) => m.OfferDetailsComponent),
        data: { isOffer: true }
    }

I am using the isOffer state to conditionally display some components. There is a search component where the search input is merged with the route, for example, offers?filter=test. I listen to queryParamsto make a request and load new offers.
During integration tests, I want to navigate to the route with queryParams before creating the component instance to process queryParams in ngOnInit.
I have tried several approaches but haven't been successful. Here's what I've tried so far:
Using RouterTestingModule and injecting the Router to navigate to offers?filter=test, but queryParams is undefined.
        router.navigate(['/offers'], 
            { 
                queryParams: { filter: 'test' }
            }
        );

Could you help me and give me any advice or solution how to solve this problem?

I am injecting Router and ActivatedRoute in TestBed to log route info, url from Router is correct but url from ActivatedRoute is empty object.

please replicate the issue on this stackblitz and update on the question

@NarenMurali I have replicate the issue stackblitz, there is an offer component which takes isOffer state from Router and queryParams from ActivatedRoute
